# Принцип работы метода componentWillUnmount в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два компонента, у каждого имеется метод componentWillUnmount:

```
class Ul extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listItems: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
            input: '',
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('LifeCycle[unmounting]: componentWillUnmount UL COMPONENT');
    }

    delete = () => {
        this.setState({
            listItems: [],
        });
    };

    render() {
        if (!this.state.listItems.length) return null;

        return (
            <>
                <ul>
                    <Li listItems={this.state.listItems} />
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

class Li extends React.Component {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('LifeCycle[unmounting]: componentWillUnmount LI COMPONENT');
    }

    items = this.props.listItems.map((item, id) => (
        <li key={id}>
            {item}
        </li>
    ));

    render() {
        return <>{this.items}</>;
    }
};
```

Если нажать на кнопку "Delete", то state изменится (массив очистится) и при повторном рендеринге код споткнется об условие:

```
if (!this.state.listItems.length) return null;
```

При этом в консоли будет выведено - **LifeCycle[unmounting]: componentWillUnmount LI COMPONENT**
Я ожидал подобного сообщения и от компонента UL, но не получил его.

Я так понимаю это происходит из за того, что функция render в компоненте UL все же выполнилась, а значит метод жизненного цикла для этого компонента был следующий:

*Update: getDerivedStateFromProps => shouldComponentUpdate => render => getSnapshotBeforeUpdate => componentDidUpdate*

то есть он был для компонента UL в состоянии **Update** а не **Unmounting** и именно по этому не было никаких причин для вызова метода *componentWillUnmount*. В то время как управление вообще не дошло до компонента LI он вызвал метод *componentWillUnmount*. То есть *componentWillUnmount* для текущего компонента не будет вызываться если дело уже дошло до функции render в нем?

Еще вопрос: Если в компоненте UL в return на первое условие не указывать null, то вызовется метод *componentWillUnmount* этого компонента. Казалось бы наконец - то, вот только вместе с ним вызовутся две три ошибки в консоли. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) вызывается *перед удалением из DOM*.

В случае удаления элементов из `items` - `LI` удаляются из DOM - для них, закономерно вызывается обработчик.

Компонент `UL` продолжает оставаться в `DOM` - для него не вызывается обработчик.

---

Если ты убираешь `return null`. При попытке отрендерить `LI` получаешь ошибку и все выполнение прерывается, следовательно и основной компонент тоже не рендерится и убирается из DOM.